# extract only certain rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
     Code       Date         Open    High    Low    Close     Volume     VWAP    TWAP
0  US_GWA_BTC 2014-04-01    467.28  488.62  467.28  479.56  74,776.48   482.76  482.82
1   GWA_BTC   2014-04-02    479.20  494.30  431.32  437.08  114,052.96  460.19  465.93
2   GWA_BTC   2014-04-03    437.33  449.74  414.41  445.60  91,415.08   432.29  433.28
.
```

`316 MWA_XRP_US 2018-01-19    1.57    1.69    1.48    1.53  242,563,870.44  1.59    1.59
 317 MWA_XRP_US 2018-01-20    1.54    1.62    1.49    1.57  140,459,727.30  1.56    1.56`

I want to filter out rows where code which has `GWA` infront of it.

I tried this code but it's not working.
`df.set_index("Code").filter(regex='[GWA_]*', axis=0)`

Comment: Looks to me like your regex is wrong. [GWA_] means a set of those characters, not that string.

Comment: @Denziloe what should my regex be in that case?

Comment: Regex is a big topic, check out this resource: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html For your example, you want `^GWA`. This pattern means "starts with GWA".

Comment: @Denziloe I tried this but it doesn't work `df.set_index("Code").filter(regex='$GWA', axis=0)`

Comment: Starts with ^ not $.

Comment: @Denziloe That worked. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html):

```
df[df.Code.str.startswith('GWA')]
```

Comment: if the string was like this `"US_GWA_BTC"` how can we use the above code then?

Comment: @SaiKumar change to `str.contains`

Comment: @Wen Is it possible to use `filter` to do this?

Comment: If you really want to use `filter`, you can: `df.set_index('Code').filter(regex='GWA', axis='index')`, but I don't really see the advantage to this

Comment: @SaiKumar `df.set_index("Code").filter(like='GWA', axis=0)
`